# Why has Chrome lost all my saved passwords?

Tags: google-chrome, osx-snow-leopard, passwords

I'm using Google Chrome on Mac OSX (Snow Leopard.)

I had it set to "Offer to save passwords".  I used to have a list (when I clicked "manage saved passwords") of various websites and logins.

Now that list is empty.

**Where have all my passwords gone?**

(I'd also be interested in useful search terms to help me find similar experiences on the web, for trouble-shooting.)

Comment: I've never used Chrome's password storing feature, but can you find some in *Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, Chrome (also?) puts your  passwords into the general password storage for OS X, which is the *Keychain*.

Open it from */Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app*. You will probably find your passwords there. Here, look for the kind "Internet passwords".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this problem yesterday (but only realized it today). I suspect it has to do with the [sync](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139&topic=1693469&ctx=topic) feature in Chrome. In my case, I have been using Google Chrome for about 2 years, and it's even synced most recently with my iPod Touch and iPad 3. I've used a Win7 Laptop and Desktop, so that's **4 computers** that share the synced data. It's a great feature.

I probably had close to 200 saved ids/passwords, with all the various stuff I used for home and work. On *all* of my Chrome instances, the data was gone (!). My girlfriend encountered the same problem, but she only has an HP Laptop.

There are [more than a few complaints](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/iLpzO8OC2wM) about this, <del>but I haven't found anything from the Chrome team that explains how it happens</del>. **Edit** [It's a bug in Chrome with iOS.](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/iTl_7DgUpkc/NW2kc7mc7c0J)

There are two possibilities: 1) the data got wiped from the Google server where the syncs are stored in the cloud (although my Bookmarks are still good across all the Chrome versions), or 2) one of the *n* Chrome instances uploaded empty (or corrupted) sync data, causing it to propagate to all my other Chrome instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you use multiple users on chrome, you may find several features of chrome failing, as well as some web apps. I've tested it on a completely clean laptop. worked for 2 days with no issues and than created 2 new chrome user. from that point, chrome fails to save any password,  and password cookies are dropped on restart since they are usually stored in memory and not in disk.
solution: you have to choose between having your passwords saved, and having multiple users. 
since I need several users, I try using firefox for the few sites that I want the passwords saved. hopefully Google will fix that one time, though I see no interest for them to invest resources in this.